# Web appliaction using struts2 cannot include css file

Tags: css, jsp, struts2

I am trying to include a CSS to my JSP and I tried a lot of suggestions from the internet but none of them works for me.

Grateful if anyone can help!

### My JSP class:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/Login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>test</p>
<s:form action="loginAction" method="post">
    <s:textfield type="text" label="User Name:" name="username"/>
    <s:password type="text" label="Password: " name="password"/>
    <s:submit value="login" type="submit"/>
</s:form>   
</body>
</html>
```

### My CSS class:

```
p {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
}
```

### My directory:

```
WebContent
 - css/Login.css
 - WEB-INF
 - ... jsp -s
...
```

Comment: Can you show  css file in the browser?

Comment: That is a good way to check, I found the problem now. I actually have a filter class that restrict the access of the css file. Now I can load the css file with some changes to my filter class. Thank you so much!